# Best practice to map localized user input to internal value in Android?

Tags: java, android, localization, user-input

In my Android App I have a settings Activity with a drop down menus where users can set their preferences, for instance their gender. The drop down menu contains several options in the localized form, say in German the options for female, male and other: "Weiblich", "Männlich", "Andere".

How to I convert the localized strings from the view into an internal representation that I can store at the server - and vice versa, the value from the server to the localized string?

All I've come up with so far is having a hard coded if-else statement, which seems a bad idea:

```
private String getSelectedGender() {
        String selectedGender = genderSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (selectedGender.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.Female))) {
            return "female";
        } else if // ...
                  // ...
    }
```

Same for the other way, from internal represntation to view:

```
private void setGenderInView(User user) {
        String gender = user.getGender();
        String localizedGender;
        if (gender.equalsIgnoreCase("female")) {
            localizedGender = getResources().getString(R.string.Male);
        } //...
    }
```

It would be nice if I could just get the key of the resource `<string name="female">Weiblich</string>`.

I feel this is such a common problem in localized applications that there should be some general solution - I just can't think how.

Comment: You are right! The localization should not interfere with your application logic. Check out androids adapters like the `ArrayAdapter`. They can act as the magic glue between the actual data (your users) and the ui (the spinner). You will add items to adapter. Only the adapter is responsible for looking up the translations and creating the views for the spinner. Your application logic will work on theese non-localized items directly. There are loads of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use for this type of localization problem is to use a `Pair` object or create a POJO if I need to store more data than just two things.

But for your case, a `Pair` should work just fine. You can create one like this:

```
Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<>(INTERNAL_STRING, LOCALIZED_STRING);
```

Basically, rather than just passing in an array or list of Strings into the Spinner's adapter, you would pass in an array or list of `Pair` objects. Each `Pair` object will possess the localized String and an internal String.

Of course, this does call for a custom adapter for your Spinner, but it's not difficult to create one if you're not already using a custom one. In your custom Spinner adapter, you will simply have it display the localized String from the Pair object.

Then when you're getting the results, simply fetch the internal String from the `Pair` object that's returned to you.

Both of your solutions require too much checks when retrieving the user's result, which can get quite hectic if your data set is larger than just simple Genders. Imagine all the If Statements needed if your Spinner was used for Countries o.o

So with this solution, there's no need to perform any checks. You just need to retrieve the internal value that you've already stored. There's a distinction between the localized String and the internal String, which makes it quick and easy for you to retrieve either String for use within your app.